# Can't sending data from View to Controller

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

can you help about that issue?
I am trying to pass my data to the controller. Below you can see my ajax code.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).on("click", "#login_button", function () {

        var userName = document.getElementById("userName").value;
        var password = document.getElementById("password").value;

        if (userName !== "" && password !== "") {

            $.ajax({

                url: '/Home/Login',
                type: 'POST',
                contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
                data: {
                    'userName' : userName,
                    'password' : password
                },
                datatype: 'json',
                success: function (data) {
                }


            })
        }
        else {
            alert("Lütfen Alanları Doldurunuz.")

        }
    })


</script>
```

And my controller is like,

```
   [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(string userName, string password)
    {
        return View();
    }
```

I checked my data and it is not empty or null. How can I fix it?

Now I am getting this error =

```
jquery.min.js:4 POST http://localhost:59277/Home/Login 500 (Internal Server Error)
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Your code is sending post request and it's allowed only HTTPGET so change it on either javascript or c# side, both will work.

Comment: Your AJAX is using POST and your Server is allowing GET. Both need to use the same HTTP verb type.

Comment: i did HttpGet to HttpPost and i put debugger to my controller, still i can't get the data

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today during a programming competition.
What solved it for me was using a different way of sending a GET request:

```
    $.get("URL/to/send/request/to", function(data, status){
        alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);//data is the actual response you get, while status is weather the request was successful
    });
});
```

Hope it works for you too.

Answer (score 0):

i thik you should use

```
 url: 'http://stackoverflow.com/Home/Login',
```

instead of

```
Home/Login
```

Answer (score 0):

i solve my problem changing the type of ajax as "GET" and changing my controller as "HttpGet" but when I do this for "POST" it didn't solve. Can anyone explain it to me?

Answer (score 0):

```
 $.ajax({
            url: 'http://stackoverflow.com/Home/Login',
            type: "POST",
            dataType: 'json',
            data: dataToPost,

            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
            success: function (data) {
                alert("hi" + data);
            }
        });
```

i think it is work